# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'm attempting to switch from VB.NET to C#; however I'm having some issues with JSON. I'm attempting to deserialize a JSON array. However, I get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Here's the class I'm deserializing into:

```
public class ReturnObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool thumbnailFinal { get; set; }
    public string thumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public object bcOverlayUrl { get; set; }
    public object personalServerOverlayUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize code:

```
 Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnObject>(richTextBox1.Text));
```

Here's the web URL to the JSON I'm attempting to retrieve.

[http://www.roblox.com/place-thumbnails?params=[{placeId:1818}]](http://www.roblox.com/place-thumbnails?params=[%7BplaceId:1818%7D])

Comment: Show the code where you deserialize it

Comment: Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnObject>(richTextBox1.Text)); Added to the main post

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deserialize a JSON array into just a single object, which can't be done.

Change your deserialization code to this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnObject[]>(richTextBox1.Text)
```

To see the results:

```
foreach(var obj in deserialized)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That did the trick. Last question let's say I want to retrieve id or thumbnailUrl how would I do that?

Comment: You would iterate through results and get the info you need

Comment: Odd. It's displaying SomeApp.Form1+ReturnObject[]

Comment: Of course, because that's the type of an array. I'll update the code

Comment: Thank you, I do apologize for the frequent questions. I'm still a newbie.